# Substitution cipher code optimization in Python

Tags: python, string, optimization, substitution

Here is my code to test my three different functions that perform simple substitution encryption on 2000 random strings of length up to 500 with 2000 random keys.

Output shows that the best function is `encrypt3` then `encrypt1` and the slowest is `encrypt2`.

**What are other methods to perform substitution that would be even faster than `encrypt3`?**

Substitution is performed on upper-case alphabet "A" to "Z", no other characters are allowed and no tests are needed whether input strings contain only those characters.

At the end of code is a test whether all functions produced same outputs.

```
from random import randrange, seed, sample
from time import perf_counter

alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

def encrypt1(t,key):
    v=dict(zip(alphabet,key))
    return ''.join(v.get(n) for n in t)

def encrypt2(t,key):
    return ''.join(key[alphabet.index(n)] for n in t)

def encrypt3(t,key):
    return t.translate(str.maketrans(alphabet,key))
    
d=2000 # number of strings and keys to test
length=500 # biggest length of strings

strings=[''.join(chr(randrange(26)+65) for n in range(1,randrange(1,length))) for n in range(d)]

keys=[''.join(chr(n+65) for n in sample(range(26), 26)) for n in range(d)]

a=perf_counter()
en1=[encrypt1(strings[n],keys[n]) for n in range(d)]
b=perf_counter()
print('encrypt1 time:',b-a)

a=perf_counter()
en2=[encrypt2(strings[n],keys[n]) for n in range(d)]
b=perf_counter()
print('encrypt2 time:',b-a)

a=perf_counter()
en3=[encrypt3(strings[n],keys[n]) for n in range(d)]
b=perf_counter()
print('encrypt3 time:',b-a)

print("All encryptions outputs are same:",en1==en2==en3)
```

Output:

```
# encrypt1 time: 0.09787979999999999
# encrypt2 time: 0.16948359999999996
# encrypt3 time: 0.029016399999999998
# All encryptions outputs are same: True
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that you'll do better than `maketrans`, which is Python's built-in function to do exactly what you're looking for.   Why, exactly, are you trying to optimize this?

Comment: For example when you want to attack substitution cipher you need a fast encryption/decryption function - at least I guess so :-)

Comment: You typically don't crack substitution ciphers by trying all 26! possibilities.  Frequency analysis is far more important.

Comment: I know that but anyway you need to test lots of keys even though much much less than 26!.

Comment: @Frank Yellin: By the way, where I can find source code of functions `maketrans` and `translate`?

Comment: Both are implemented in C.

Comment: Why are they implemented in C? Is C faster/better for such purpose? Can they be implemented in python code with the same speed/efficiency?

Comment: Sorry.  No idea.  Presumably for speed but who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply comparing the time taking by a join without any operation and the `translante/maketrans`, you can quickly see that it is impossible to have a solution that uses join and is faster than the `translante/maketrans` implementation (see the code at the end for implementation).

```
Encryption join only took: 0.006335399999999991s
Encryption translation function took: 0.004516500000000034s
```

And knowing that strings are immutable in Python and the join is one of the fastest (if not the fastest) pure python ways to concatenate characters, it would seem hard to find a better python implementation.

However, as mentioned by frank-yellin, a C implementation can be done to make the code run faster. C code runs faster than python for low level operations like in this case (replacing character in a string).

To try out writing a C version, you can use cython which will make it a lot easier than writing all the boilerplate of an extension by yourself.

Example:
You will need to install cython: `pip install cython` and compile the cython code by ruunning `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` in the folder containing the 3 following files

```py
# file cencrypt.pyx

# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef char char_A = 'A'

def encrypt(t, key):
    cdef string key_str = key.encode('UTF-8')
    cdef string result = t.encode('UTF-8')

    for i in range(len(result)):
        result[i] = key_str[result[i]-char_A]

    return result.decode('UTF-8')
```

```py
# file main.py

from random import randrange, seed, sample
from time import perf_counter

from cencrypt import encrypt as encrypt_c

alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"


def encrypt_join_only(t, key):
    return ''.join(t)


def encrypt_dict(t, key):
    v = dict(zip(alphabet, key))
    return ''.join(v.get(n) for n in t)


def encrypt_array(t, key):
    ord_a = ord("A")
    return ''.join(key[n - ord_a] for n in map(ord, t))


def encrypt_translation(t, key):
    return t.translate(str.maketrans(alphabet, key))


d = 2000  # number of strings and keys to test
length = 500  # biggest length of strings

strings = [''.join(chr(randrange(26) + 65) for n in range(1, randrange(1, length))) for n in range(d)]
keys = [''.join(chr(n + 65) for n in sample(range(26), 26)) for n in range(d)]


def measure_perf(function, name):
    start = perf_counter()
    result = [function(strings[n], keys[n]) for n in range(d)]
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f'Encryption {name} took: {end - start}s', )
    return result


measure_perf(encrypt_join_only, "join only")
equal = (
    measure_perf(encrypt_dict, "dict lookup") ==
    measure_perf(encrypt_array, "array lookup") ==
    measure_perf(encrypt_translation, "translation function") ==
    measure_perf(encrypt_c, "cython implementation")
)

print("All encryptions outputs are same:", equal)
```

```
#file setup.py

from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("cencrypt.pyx")
)
```

Results I7:

```
Encryption join only took: 0.006335399999999991s
Encryption dict lookup took: 0.044010700000000014s
Encryption array lookup took: 0.0479598s
Encryption translation function took: 0.004516500000000034s
Encryption cython implementation took: 0.002248700000000048s
All encryptions outputs are same: True
```

Comment: You could also add the time of your "cython implementation" to compare it with `encrypt_translation` function time.

Comment: You wrote: "the join is one of the fastest (if not the fastest) pure python ways to concatenate characters". I do not understand then why it is so slow on only one string argument. `return ''.join(t)` - in fact it has nothing to join, `t` is already one single string. The `encrypt_translation` function can do in less time all these steps - 1. converting strings to list of integers, 2. make dictionary, 3. do the translation, 4. convert list of integers to characters, 5. join the characters to string. The `return ''.join(t)` has to do just the return of original argument `t`.

Comment: If you look at the implementation of [translate](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12f433411bba8a0cdc4f09ba34472745ae9da0d1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9220), you will see that for the translation you are trying to do, the implementation never does any concatenation which is a lot faster compared to the join implementation which has quite a lot of code to be able to handle any kind of lists being given as argument and actually does concatenation like operations [join](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12f433411bba8a0cdc4f09ba34472745ae9da0d1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L10239).